# Detect whether file contains text or binary

Tags: mime-types, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika to detect whether a given file is binary or text.

I'd like the following extensions (".txt", ".csv", ".log", ".bat", ".m", ".properties", ".inf", ".ini",".java", ".c", ".cpp", ".h", ".vpp" ) to be detected as text files.

I am simply using Tika.detect(file) method to do this. But I notice that some of the above extensions like .inf (which is clearly text based) and .vpp are getting wrongly detected as 'application'.

Using javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap.MimetypesFileTypeMap(), .vpp files are detected as application/octect-stream (binary). 
Using, SVNAccessControl svn:mimetype, we get type as text.

Is there a way to detect these files as text correctly in a Java program using any of these third party libs ?

Comment: According to this https://datatypes.net/open-vpp-files the mime type for .vpp is application/octet-stream. What is the output of the command `file the_file_name.vpp`?

Comment: What is the full type that Tika is detecting the problematic files as?

Comment: I do: file -bi the_file_name.vpp and it returns application/octet-stream; charset=binary. Doing file the_file_name.vpp returns SQLite 3.x database! Tika detects the full type as application/x-sqlite3